# REE rake gems:install is not working correct

Tags: rake, rubygems, ruby-enterprise-edition

I've installed REE on CentOS 5 for a very special task (using rails 2.3.10 and ruby 1.8) and I really need it to be isolated

In this case I won't use bundler or smth so.

Everything works ok if I'll setup every gem manually via

```
/opt/ree/bin/gem install agem
```

But when I run

```
/opt/ree/bin/rake gems:install
```

in prepared for this command project - all (or most, I haven't check every dependency) gems are installed via /usr/bin/gem into common gem path, where I do not need any of them

This is an issue and I do not want to install all gems manually. Have smb ever hit into this issue and probably knows solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that really helped me was to temporarily replace `/usr/bin/gem` with a symbolic link to `/opt/ree/bin/gem`

With this replacement `/opt/ree/bin/rake gems:intall` worked as expected - all required gems were installed to REE path - returning `/usr/bin/gem` to original gem executable made system stable again

This is not very *clean* solution but it works, so it can be used like hammer in critical situation.

Answer (score 0):

There's either a `GEM_HOME` variable somewhere in the environment, or the runtime ruby called is not ree. Therefore, I'd suggest at least 3 things to try:

- Start with an almost empty environment (run `env -i sh` for example) and run again the rake command, see if this is still installs gems in the common gem path. Be careful, because `env -i` is an empty environment, you might see complaints from rubygems (because no `HOME` or nothing else is set)...
- Check that the shebang line (first line of the rake program) really indicates your REE binary and not something else
- Finally, do run rake using the REE binary with `/opt/ree/bin/ruby /opt/ree/bin/rake gems:install`

This should give you an indication of what's going wrong. All in all, I think that the environment issue is probably the most probable culprit of this thing

Comment: Thank you, but no of your suggestion works - I tried every point: 1. `env -i sh` has path problems; 2. shebang line of `rake` leads to REE; 3. `/opt/ree/bin/ruby /opt/ree/bin/rake gems:install` didn't work at all (with error that ruby cannot run binary file - strange, but it's a fact)